# Writing a formula in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

In my Sharepoint library I have a field named Tooling Status.  I'm trying to use a calculation to fill the status with either "Open" or "Complete" but I can't seem to get the formula right.  What I'm trying to say with my statement is:

If Tooling is Yes and T1, T2, T3, T4 are NOT blank, Tooling Status should be marked "Complete", otherwise "Open".  (Which means tooling has to be yes and all four "T" fields must have data in them for it to be marked "Complete".  If one of the "T" fields is empty, it should still be "Open")

In addition, If Tooling is NO, tooling status is "Complete" no matter what's in the "T" Fields.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

*of the top of my head*:

```
=IF(NOT(Tooling)
    ,"Complete"
    ,IF( OR( ISBLANK(T1) , ISBLANK(T2) , ISBLANK(T3) , ISBLANK(T4) )
        ,"Open"
        ,"Complete"
       )
   )
```

Complete Function list at:

https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

Comment: Rather than showing "Open" or "Complete" the value that's returned is "#VALUE!" both when Tooling is Yes and when it's NO.

Comment: Built the formula step by step, eg. replace the whole OR function with TRUE and FALSE while testing where the error is

Comment: I am not 100% sure SP2007 had the OR function (and I can not test it)

Comment: =IF(Tooling=”NO”,”Complete”,(OR(T1="",T2="",T3="",T4="","Open","Complete")))     This works when Tooling is No, it marks Complete.  But when Tooling is Yes, it's showing "#VALUE!).

Comment: So single out the last part: first try ``IF( TRUE )
        ,"Open"
        ,"Complete"
       )`` then ``IF( OR( ISBLANK(T1) , ISBLANK(T2) , ISBLANK(T3) , ISBLANK(T4) )
        ,"Open"
        ,"Complete"
       )``

Comment: Rule of thumb for 'Programming/debugging': *If something is broken then break it apart*

Comment: Maybe even try ``=OR(TRUE)`` to test if the OR function is even available in SP2007

Comment: I'm sure trying...I keep getting syntax errors.  I believe OR is available.  This was my original funciton and it worked:  =IF(Tooling="YES",(OR(T1="",T2="",T3="",T4="","Open","Complete")))

Comment: It gives a result but has **6** tests inside the OR function

Comment: It does not seem to recognize the OR command in the function.  I'm trying to read "Help" but so far can't find any reference to IF OR statements.

Comment: ``=IF(OR(TRUE),"Hello","World")`` returns **Hello** in my SharePoint Online.  ``=IF(Tooling="YES","Complete",     IF(OR(T1="",T2="",T3="",T4=""),"Open","Complete"))``  *should* work

Comment:  But you learned Formulas!!  ... You can now click that ✔ checkmark and mark the question answered..